# How to stub val function of jquery using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-node, jasmine-jquery

My code has a line:

```
 $("#divID select").val(0)
```

I've to write a unit test using Jasmine for this. I've set up the dom elements. Can I stub val and check whether it's called on this particular selector and called with 0 as argument?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could spy the fn.val of jquery.

```
spyOn($.fn, 'val')
```

And just check if the val method was called.

```
expect($.fn.val).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I don't know how jquery works inside but I guess that he use the fn.val for every instance.

Or just mock the instance like this:

```
var instance = $("#divID select");
spyOn(instance, 'val').and.callFake(function() {
  //your mock function here
});
```